# Order of resource directories in Maven

Tags: maven-3

I would like to have my Java project using Maven set up so that when developing locally and when running unit tests, resources are taken from the standard `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` directories, while when applying a *profile* the resources are overwritten with deployment-specific ones. Ideally, the profile specific resources will be a subset of the full resources, so the process should work by first writing the regular resources, then applying the profile specific ones on top of the first.

My directory layout is the standard one, with the *profiles* resources under `src/main/env/{profile}`.

I managed to do this using multiple stanzas under `build`/`resources`:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
      <properties>
        <targetEnv>dev</targetEnv>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
        <targetEnv>test</targetEnv>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <targetEnv>prod</targetEnv>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

 <build>
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/env/${targetEnv}</directory>
     </resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
  <build>
```

This is working, however, my first attempt was with the two resource directories ordered in the opposite way (first the regular directory, the the profile specific one), in a way to match the overwriting process. Instead, it was overwriting the profile specific files with the regular ones.

Does Maven guarantee an order for the stanzas under `build`/`resources` at all?

Comment: The guarantee is for unit test having first on the classpath `src/test/resources` and afterwards `src/main/resources`... You should build your artifacts environment specific...using profiles will not work for making releases...So I recommend to take a look at  https://github.com/khmarbaise/multienv-maven-plugin